# image in rtl language in the footer

Tags: html, css, image, right-to-left

i am using opencart i installed a custom footer as it preview  my Facebook page and so on .. the problem  is that i am using Arabic language so it is an RTL format so my icon in the title is not correct as it is in English it is suppose to be in the right of the text but it is not ...

i tried `background-position: 100% 0;` but it put the image below the text ...

so any ideas

my website is : [www.egy-smoke.com](http://www.egy-smoke.com)

Comment: Try using another <div> for your image to hold your image and change place of <div> instead of changing image position.

Comment: Please provide us some of your HTML or CSS code u are using.

Answer (score 0):

Update your custom style sheet, so this:

```
footer #custom-footer > div > div > div h3.facebook {
padding-left: 34px;
background: url(../img/icon-facebook.png) 0px 9px no-repeat;
}
```

becomes like this:

```
footer #custom-footer > div > div > div h3.facebook {
  padding-right: 34px;
  background: url(../img/icon-facebook.png) 100% 9px no-repeat;
}
```

Repeat the above for other custom items like 'اتصل بنا' and 'احنا مين'